# How can I move the contents of one directory tree into another?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a directory which contains files and a number of levels of subdirectories:

```
C:\Source
```

I would like to move the contents of C:\Source into:

```
C:\Destination
```

Requirements:

- All files and all subdirectories
  *within* C:\SourceData must be moved
- I will be running the command in a
  batch file
- I can't use Powershell or
  any other scripting languages

**Attempt 0**

```
XCOPY /E "C:\Source" "C:\Destination"
```

This works perfectly, but it copies instead of moves. I can't copy then delete the source as I'm moving a very large set of files and there isn't enough disk space to have two copies of them at a time.

**Attempt 1**

```
MOVE "C:\Source" "C:\Destination"
```

This moves the entire C:\Source directory *into* C:\Destination so I end up with:

```
C:\Destination\Source
```

**Attempt 2**

With some help from [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210413) I came up with:

```
for /r "C:\Source" %%x in (*) do move "%%x" "C:\Destination"
```

This moves the files within C:\Source but not the subdirectories or their contents. Note that I used %%x instead of %x as I'm using it in a batch file.

Using FOR seems promising but I'm not sure I've used the right syntax? Have I missed something?

**Attempt 3**

As suggested by Nick D, I tried rename:

RENAME "C:\Source" Destination

For the example scenario I gave this works fine. Unfortunately my real *Destination* directory is at a different level to the *Source* directory and this doesn't seem to be supported:

```
C:\>REN /?
Renames a file or files.

RENAME [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.
REN [drive:][path]filename1 filename2.

Note that you cannot specify a new drive or path for your destination file.
```

I get "The syntax of the command is incorrect." errors if I try to specify a more complex destination path, for example:

```
RENAME "C:\Source" "C:\MyOtherDirectory\Destination"
RENAME "C:\Source" "MyOtherDirectory\Destination"
```

Comment: Whilst MOVE will move the "source" *into* "destination" if "destination" already exists, it will move "source" *to* "destination" if it does not already exist.

Comment: If RENAME worked as you wanted, then you could have moved to the right folder with a temporary name, and then renamed :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**:

Adjusted code to a. check whether folders already exist at the destination, in which case move files in that folder over (and continue traversing the source directory structure), otherwise move the folder wholesale.

At the end of the script the source folder is removed altogether to eliminate these folders which have had their files moved over to an already existent folder at the destination (meaning these folders have been emptied but not deleted at the source).

Additionally we check whether a folder is both empty and already exists at the destination in which case we do nothing (and leave the source folder to be deleted to the last line of the script). Not doing this results in "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." errors.

Phew! Please let me know how you get on with this! I have tested this and it seems to be working well.

```
for /d /r "c:\source" %%i in (*) do if exist "c:\destination\%%~ni" (dir "%%i" | find "0 File(s)" > NUL & if errorlevel 1 move /y "%%i\*.*" "c:\destination\%%~ni") else (move /y "%%i" "c:\destination")
move /y c:\source\*.* c:\destination
rd /s /q c:\source
```

Comment: I needed to change the FOR command to use %%i instead of %i (as it's in a batch file) but other than that it works great. Thank you!

Comment: Yay! That really was a guess to be honest. Noticed /D in the for help screen and took a shot... I updated the %%i thing :)

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's not working after all. I'm getting "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." when running the move command.

Comment: OK, I've significantly updating the answer to try to address issues I found with it in the first place, hope it sorts it now!

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try but have run out of time for now. I went with the robocopy option in the end as it's easier to read and understand for whoever inherits my code at a later date.

Comment: `%%~ni` strips the extension, so a folder name with a dot will break - change to `%%~nxi`.

Answer (score 37):

Undoubtedly use robocopy. It is a simple but brilliantly useful tool.

```
robocopy /move /e sourcedir destdir
```

This will move all the files and folders, including empty ones, deleting each original file after it has moved it.

If you don't have robocopy installed you can download it by itself or as part of a Microsoft resource kit.

Comment: +1: I'd forgotten about robocopy being able to move (must be the name!). In my case I can't rely on robocopy being installed but I could easily include the binary alongside the script.

Comment: Yeah - and what's nice is it doesn't have any dependencies; it is just one .exe and works fine on Vista, Server 2003, 2008, etc. So long as you can store it with the script you'll have a robust and reliable process.

Comment: It is a good answer but it actually copies first and then deletes.  If you are moving a large directory structure this would take a while.  While just manually moving it in explorer would be almost instantaneous because all it would be doing is updating the MFT.

Comment: Ferris Bueller you're my hero. Thank you!

Comment: Note that `robocopy` is [built into with Windows starting with Windows Vista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy#Versions).

Answer (score 3):

In response to ufukgun's answer:

```
xcopy C:\Source\* C:\Destination\* /s /e /i /Y
```

/s - Copies directories and subdirectories except empty ones.
/e - Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.
/i - If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory.
/y - Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

As stated in another answer, using xcopy may be not as efficient as it would be a native move command that only changes pointers in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Since XCOPY works, you could use XCOPY and DELETE, it's a workaround, but should work?

Comment: That would work for a lot of cases but unfortunately I can't copy then delete the source as I'm moving a very large set of files and there isn't enough disk space to have two copies of them at a time. I've updated the question to clarify this, I should have mentioned it before.

Answer (score 1):

on Vista use

```
robocopy source destination /MIR

/MIR .. mirror a complete directory tree (also deletes files in the destination)
```

else

```
xcopy
```

Of course you have to delete the source afterwards :)

Comment: That would work for a lot of cases but unfortunately I can't copy then delete the source as I'm moving a very large set of files and there isn't enough disk space to have two copies of them at a time. I've updated the question to clarify this, I should have mentioned it before.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a directory which contains
>   files and a number of levels of
>   subdirectories:
>
> C:\Source
>
> I would like to move the contents of
>   C:\Source into:
>
> C:\Destination

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just rename the folder?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work if the Destination directory isn't at the same level as the Source directory. I'll add more detail to the question rather than this comments box.

Answer (score 1):

As sent on twitter:
Try combining attempt 3 with attempt 1. Rename to get the destination folder correct, then move "Destination" to the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo on
set SOURCE=C:\Source
set DESTINATION=C:\Destination

xcopy %SOURCE%\* %DESTINATION%\* /s /e /i /Y

PAUSE
```

i use batch file like this...

or simply call:

```
xcopy C:\Source\* C:\Destination\* /s /e /i /Y
```

Comment: What do those /s /e /i /Y switches do? Do they make it move the files rather than copy them?

Answer (score 1):

I use a utility called xxcopy. It can move files and have many useful options, you can use it like this :

```
xxcopy C:\Source C:\Destination /E /RC
```

the options :

- /E to copy everything even empty folders
- /RC to remove every source file after each successful copy

you can download free copy of xxcopy for personal use from :
http://www.xxcopy.com/xcpydnld.htm

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little off-topic, but still usefull:

Some people suggest to just copy + delete the source files, but
moving files is not the same as copying + deleting!

When using the **(x)copy** function, you **allocate new space** on the **same volume** on a harddisk. After the copying the files, the **old** files (the old allocated space which was required for the files) are beign marked as **deleted**. While you will achieve the same result as an end-user, moving does something diffrent and more efficient.

**Moving** files actually only changes some records in the **MFT** (master file table). These changes only consist of a different path for the user to locate its files. Physically the files still remain in the same sectors on the harddisk.

Comment: If not using xcopy or Robocopy, what would you suggest to move folders ?

Answer (score 0):

If all your trying to do is move a directory and the content up one level:

```
MOVE folder_you_wan_to_move ..
```

Note that .. refers to the next directory up.

Answer (score 0):

I leave this code I have written based on ljs's attempt,
It moves directory trees as Windows does, overwriting the files that already exists in destination with those in source, and avoiding the slow copy and erase method except if the destination is in a different drive.

If your S.O is not in english must change line 6 with the text used by the Dir command when it finds 0 files.

**movedir.bat *source_dir destination_dir***

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL  ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

if %1.==. echo movedir dir1[\*] dir2 & echo move dir1 inside dir2 overwriting coincident files & echo option \* moves only dir1 content & goto end

set S=%~f1
set D=%~f2
set "noFiles= 0 File"
set "R=0"         rem R is option [\*] flag

if %S:~-2%.==\.. set "S=%S:~,-2%" & set "R=1"

if not exist "%S%" goto paramERR
if not exist "%D%" goto paramERR

set "Trim=0" & set "Sc=%S%"
:LP
set /A Trim+=1 & (set "Sc=!Sc:~1!") & if NOT !Sc!.==. goto LP

if %R%==0 (if exist "%D%\%~n1%~x1" (set "D=%D%\%~n1%~x1")) else move /y "%S%" "%D%" & goto end

CALL:movefiles "%S%" "%D%"
for /D /R "%S%" %%I in (*) do (set "Way=%%~fI") & (set "Way=!Way:~%Trim%!") & if exist "%D%!Way!" (CALL:movefiles "%%I" "%D%!Way!") else (move /y "%%I" "%D%!Way!\.." > NUL)
rd /s/q "%S%" & if %R%==1 md "%S%"
goto end

:movefiles 
dir %1 | find "%noFiles%" > NUL & if ERRORLEVEL 1 move /y "%~1\*.*" %2 > NUL 
goto :eof

:paramERR
echo Source or Destination does not exist
:end
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest thing you could do is to modify your Attempt 2

from

```
MOVE "C:\Source" "C:\Destination"
```

to

```
MOVE "C:\Source\*" "C:\Destination"
```

KISS ;-)

**Edit**: this seem not to work, so my advice is to trash away the crappy DOS command line and use Cygwin with BASH as a shell! (or just add the cygwin binaries to the path so you can use `mv` within DOS, thus not having to change the shell as your requirements state).

Comment: That's very simple but doesn't work. Subdirectories within C:\Source aren't copied