# Windows batch file unable to move files to another directory

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

Appreciate any help as windows 7 keeps giving following message in spite of directory exists.
Sample code with error message are below. Thanks in advance

```
D:\WebService\Project-Print-Services>move C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build\* C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I have verified COMPSEC and it is cmd.exe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move the contents of one directory tree into another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118540/how-can-i-move-the-contents-of-one-directory-tree-into-another)

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to copy folders (that error message appears when the folder is empty) then see if this helps:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build\*") do move "%%a" "C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work\"
```

Note that for running this from the command-line, you should drop one '`%`' sign,
like this:

```
for /d %a in ("C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build\*") do move "%a" "C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work\"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, actually source directory build does have many files.

Comment: Thanks after adding foxidrive suggested above command, it works though not sure why would other move do not work. Big Thanks Foxidrive.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `PowerShell`

```
Move-Item -path  C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build -destination C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work
```

`Move-Item` will not overwrite any existing files in the target folder if you dnt use `-force` option

Comment: Why would power shell help? Surely we should work out what's wrong with using `move`, a command that is known to work.

Comment: if this step is just of many steps which can be combined in a script....then why not use `powershell`...

Answer (score 1):

do both the folders exist and have files in them?

Try 
dir C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build\

dir C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work\

Do you want to move the files in side build to work or move the directory build to work?
Your current command will do the former.

To move the folder Remove the \* and add /y:

```
 move /y C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work
```

From some other dir than build

Comment: Thanks for the response. Both source and target does have files. Same move works in windows XP, keep failing only in windows 7 32 bit, not tried in 64 bit though.

Comment: if you can use java or VB script can write an app in that (extension will be .vbs can call from command prompt) http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/ezine/ezine36.htm and http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/filesfolders/files/

Comment: do you want to move the files in the folder or the complete directory?

Comment: Actually move all files from build to work, so other process could pick those files for further processing.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me, but if `C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build` is empty, you get an error message. Use the following code to avoid this:

```
dir C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build /a-d >nul 2>&1 && move C:\Temp\pdfMerge\build\* C:\Temp\pdfMerge\work
```

Comment: Actually full code is below which works perfectly well on XP 

set BASE=D:\WebService\Project-Print-Services
set INVOICE_BASE=C:\Temp\pdfMerge
set PRINTER_NAME=pdfFactory
set LIB=%BASE%\dist\lib

set CLASSPATH=.;%LIB%\*

move %INVOICE_BASE%\build\* %INVOICE_BASE%\work\

java -Dlog4j.configuration=%BASE%\config\log4j.properties -classpath %CLASSPATH% com.example.print.service.BatchPrint "%INVOICE_BASE%"

Comment: OK, but this was **not** your question.

Comment: Actually showed only the portion which was causing the hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

save this in a .vbs file, call it fom command prompt. (see comments)

```
' arg1 - folder to move
' arg2 - parent folder to move to
' call this with trailing \ in 2nd arg only
'  C:\apps\xamps\x182\htdocs\pages\prog\vba\moveFile.vbs c:\apps\a3 c:\tmp\a\
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'MsgBox "a " & WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
'checks and stops if folder does not exist
Set f =  objFSO.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments.Item(0))
Set f =  objFSO.GetFolder(WScript.Arguments.Item(1))
objFSO.MoveFolder  WScript.Arguments.Item(0) , WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
```

Comment: Oops, VBS is pretty off the block for me

Comment: Well this is not complicated vb its simple, pretty self explanatory from the function names. Take it or not, its there.\